# Why does "(#2) Service Temporarily Unavailable" in FBAudienceNetwork?

Tags: android, facebook, ads, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Facebook Interstitial Ads return **(#2) Service temporarily unavailable** error message in my Android App. Anyone have any idea what exact problem with Facebook Ads SDK. How do I resolve this error? Please Help...

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue as well.

Comment: @venkat, As per facebook guidelines facebook doesn't provide Ads for your app. So Sometimes SDK returns this type of error.

Comment: Is it happening only on the testing phase? or is it happening in production release of the apps too?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when testing ads. **Clear data and cache** can solve this problem. success.

Answer (score -1):

If you have show the other Ad. you have to destory/remove the one first. for example: AdBanner was showed, if you want to show intertitialAD, you have to destory/remove the AdBanner first.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Please provide additional information, links, your research.